# Eclipse Toolbar Layout Bug

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I have a modular application with many plug-ins. In particular there is one that contributes a toolbar to the coolbar:

```
<menuContribution allPopups="false" locationURI="toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar">
  <toolbar id="calculation" />
</menuContribution>
```

A second plug-in contributes the command and the placement (actually, it's a plug-in and its fragment, but I hope that that's not the problem):

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
  <command id="myCalculation"
           name="My Calculation">
  </command>
</extension>

<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
  <menuContribution allPopups="false" locationURI="toolbar:calculation">
    <command commandId="myCalculation" style="push">
      <visibleWhen checkEnabled="true" />
    </command>
  </menuContribution>
</extension>
```

And finally, a third plug-in hooks a handler to the command:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
  <handler class="org.acme.MyCalculationHandler" commandId="myCalculation">
    <enabledWhen>
      <!-- some stuff -->
    </enabledWhen>
  </handler>
```

While this approach works for dropdown items and menus and sub-menus and really everything, it does not work for the coolbar. The commands are shown, but they are not positioned the right way:

[image]

*(There are two commmands hiding under the save command.)*

The moment the plug-in that defines the toolbar ID adds a own contribution, the bug vanishes. I have no idea where to even start debugging this problem. Can anyone give me a pointer? Thanks.